# Disable Username & Password and only allow SSO on KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We are planning to use KeyCloak to grant access to our multi-cluster and multi-account AWS EKS infrastructure using KeyCloak. Only want to use sing-in using Google SSO/Azure AD and disable Username & Password completely i.e. even not allowing POST requests. How can I achieve this?